# How to create a Treeview Content Provider?

Tags: java, treeview, swt, jface

I want to create a `Treeview` for an Eclipse-Plugin.

I generated the `Treeview` with:

```
_viewer = new TreeViewer(parent,SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION); 
_viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());

_viewer.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
_viewer.getTree().setLinesVisible(true);
_viewer.setAutoExpandLevel(1);

TreeViewerColumn column = new TreeViewerColumn(_viewer, SWT.NONE);
column.getColumn().setText("Package / CCID");
column.getColumn().setWidth(120);
column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){

        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return "test";
        }
        }
);

column = new TreeViewerColumn(_viewer, SWT.NONE);
column.getColumn().setText("Stage");
column.getColumn().setWidth(100);
column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){

    public String getText(Object element) {
        return "test";
    }
});
```

Now I want to fill the `Treeview` with Data from DB2.
DB2 contains a table with the name "Package" and a table with the name CCID.

At first I want to list all packages in the table. Then I want to expand the package and show all CCID´s for each package.

For example:

```
+ package 1
+ package 2
+ package 3
```

and expended:

```
- package 1
   ccid 1
   ccid 2
   ccid 3
- package 2
   ccid 54
   ccid 34
   ccid 23
- package 3
   ccid 32
   ccid 23
   ccid 23
```

Is there any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are having problems with. Have you read any tutorials [like this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm) on TreeViewer?

Comment: Hey Greg, i have problems to expand a object. For example: I want to expand an created object. For example: In the tutorial I want to expand each book object and not only the subject. Do you have any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404594/how-to-expand-an-object-in-a-treeviewer Here is a new link